# How to achieve a toggle button (more/less) using jquery html() method

Tags: jquery

**This is my current jquery code . It changes the button value to less . but not the other way around.**

```
$("p").hide();

$(".btn").click(function()
{


 $("p").toggle();

 $(".btn").html("less");

 $(".btn").html("more");

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
$("p").hide();
$(".btn").html("more");
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $("p").toggle();
  if($('p').css('display') == 'none') {
    $(".btn").html("more");
  } else {
    $(".btn").html("less");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$( ".btn" ).toggle(function() {
  $(".btn").html("less");
}, function() {
  $(".btn").html("more");
});
```

The above two functions that are declared inside the toggle function will be used to toggle between the text `less` and `more`.

I doubt that you are trying to change the text of the button if yes then use `.val()` instead of `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  alert($(this).val())
  if ($(this).val() == 'more') {
    $(this).val('less')
  } else {
    $(this).val('more')
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='more' />
```

Do it like this. If you are using other elements without value just change the `.val()` to `.text() or .html()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
$(".btn").on('click', function(){

  if ($(this).text() == "less")
    {
      $(this).text('more')
    }
  else
    {
       $(this).text('less')
    }

});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn">less</button>
```